# Hex Decoding in Android

Tags: android, json, web-services, hex

I am new to android. I am using the Web services to get the data from the server where I server returning data as  **\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627 \u0643\u064a\u0641** In real this is Arabic text, so could you please suggest mw how should I decode this Data to the required language. However the server returns the this data in the Arabic form if I don't mention the Header as
    mHttpGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

But if don't mention the header I get the response in the XML format, But as I try to get the data in json format it shows me the Arabic data in form of Hex String as mentioned above in bold font. Please suggest me how should I convert the data in the required format. your help would appreciative thanks.